# SCSS combine :hover and @if

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to combine the following code and using the :hover selector and @if statement together?

```
$active: true;

button {
  &:hover {
    color: red;
  }

  @if $active {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

This is the thing I'd like to do:

```
button {
  &:hover,
  & @if $active {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, no. It has to do the hover thing no matter if the $active variable is set to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually kind of achieve this using `$var: if();`. It could look something like this:

```
$target: if(true, "&", "");

a { 
  &:hover,
  #{$target} {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

More info on `if()` here: http://thesassway.com/news/sass-3-3-released#if

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. It may be a strange solution and I ended up doing this with a mixin, but I've learned another thing, thank you for that:)

Comment: And be careful with the coma here : `&:hover,`.
One simple way to handle it is to put an undefined thing instead of empty selector :  `$target: if(true, "&", "i-am-not-existing");`

Comment: @long-lazuli: I was also concerned about this originally but it appears as though Sass just ignores the trailing comma. For example: `body, { background: blue; }`

Comment: Thanx @graygilmore I did not know that !